# Heavy load Map application. where to start?

Tags: web-mapping, google-maps-api, hosting

I want to start building a quite big project that I have in mind that is 99% based on the world map. I have worked with Google maps in the past and know how to use their api and I have done some research on other solutions like open street map. I want to build a web Application that will need most of the functionality that the google javascript Api provides (markers,event handlers, map data, geocoding, directions ,etc).

But google has the usage limits policy which could become a great burden for my application if the traffic rises to huge amounts. So I would like to know if there is a way to get an open source javascript api and maps (like the ones from open street map) and host them on my own server in order to avoid the javascript api usage limits. Any thoughts on that? Any other possible workarounds?

PS. Sorry if my questions seem silly to you but I am new to GIS and I do not have the knowledge or experience to find those answers on my own.

EDIT: I have to mention that what I actually need is a map from a predefined zoom level with the functionality stated above. The traffic is sure to become really heavy and that is the reason why I need solutions without any limits when it gets to calling an API. Last but not least, when I am saying that I would like to host my own maps actually I mean probably hosting the tiles that I need and somehow use them in addition with the API in order to show the result to the end user. From a little research done I understood that organizations like open street maps also hold the actual data (like road names etc) in special databases. I would also need to have a connection to one of those as I also need the information related to the map. If it helps,you may think of my app like a gps navigation app without any limits because of huge traffic and a lot of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at:

- OpenStreetMap (http://www.openstreetmap.org) which provide open maps, as an alternative of Google Maps tiles.
- OpenLayers (http://openlayers.org) or Leaflet (http://leafletjs.com) which are open source javascript mapping APIs. They both provide facilities for working with OSM data, or other map providers. They also come with a lot of documentation and example to get started with.

If you want to host your own maps, go with Geoserver (http://geoserver.org) or Mapserver (http://mapserver.org). But unless you have a really heavy traffic, I'm not sure it is the right way to go to host the world map by yourself. Services like OSM are made for this, they will save you time and infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! however, I have already checked both open layers and open street map and I am still not sure if this is what I am searching for. I am going to add an edit in my original question to explain further! As for the servers that you proposed to me, I get that they are software like apache but specialized in map hosting. But this means that I would have to build the whole map again on my own right? like adding street info etc ?

Comment: They are not exactly softwares like apache. They are server applications that offer services for sharing geospatial data over the web (or a private network), using standard mapping web services protocols, such as WMS or WFS. They help you distribute the data, but getting the data stays your job. I do not know exactly what you want to achieve, but from what I read in your edit, I think OSM is the way to go, maybe you should also check Mapquest (open.mapquest.com). Combine it with a js mapping library and you're good. Hosting yourself the worldmap seems to me a bit too ambitious...